# Where can I find tensorflow.contrib.layers for TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

I have been developing machine learning codes in TensorFlow with `contrib.layers`. I am happy with the module; it works very well and provides me sufficient control over my model. However, TensorFlow 2.0 will completely remove `contrib` module and the new `keras` module does not provide me enough flexibility and control without extra efforts (personal experience, correct me if I am wrong), even though it is easier to write.

I want to know where the `contrib` module will be in TensorFlow 2.0. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [RFC document from August 2018](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md), `tf.contrib` will be deleted with some of its parts becoming standalone projects (such as [tensorflow/probability](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability)).

This is the case for `tf.conrib.layers`. Even `tf.layers` (which was distilled from `tf.contrib.layers`) will no longer be supported. A detailed description of how to use the Keras API instead is provided in the [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/migration_guide#models_based_on_tflayers).

Comment: Can you update the link to the migration guide? This one seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow.contrib is a home of volatile or experimental code. It grew rapidly from version to version and got enormously large. Tensorflow 2.0 brought some breaking code changes such as deprecation of scopes, eager execution and focus on keras code. Tensorflow team decided to deprecate tensorflow.contrib while salvaging some of it's parts. You can get more information about that in ["Sunsetting tf.contrib"](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) RFC. Also, feel free to indicate to Tensorflow team which parts you find useful or even help them move to TF2.0.

I assembled 20 of the most popular (according to github usages in python code) contrib subpackages and their fate:

- **Package name (num github usages) -- fate -- refer to**
- contrib.boosted_trees (19393) -- delete (moved to core) -- [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/estimators/boosted_trees)
- contrib.distributions (106634) -- delete (moved to [probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/overview))
- contrib.eager (23699) -- move to core
- contrib.estimator (18255) -- move to tensorflow/estimator
- contrib.factorization (17834) -- delete
- contrib.framework (149940) -- partially move to core, delete the rest
- contrib.gan (28247) -- move to separate repo
- contrib.keras (37804) -- delete
- contrib.layers (212481) -- partial move to tensorflow/contrib?
- contrib.learn (167455) -- delete (replaced by tensorflow/estimator)
- contrib.metrics (27793) -- delete (replaced with OO metrics)
- contrib.rnn (84067) -- replace with new RNN API
- contrib.seq2seq (18917) -- adapt, move to core
- contrib.slim (261656) -- move to tensorflow/models?
- contrib.tensor_forest (37377) -- delete (moving to core)
- contrib.timeseries (27197) -- move to tensorflow/estimator
- contrib.tpu (25446) -- move to core -- [tf.tpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/tpu)
- contrib.training (48928) -- ??
- contrib.util (41627) -- delete (no owner), or move to tools

It seems a little disturbing that [tensorflow.contrib](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=%22tensorflow.contrib%22&type=Code) with 970K usages is deprecated while whole TF has 4M all together.

Comment: How about `contrib.graph_editor`? Awesome answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

Some projects from `tf.contrib` are moving to core (e.g. `tf.contrib.lite`, `tf.contrib.tpu`). Some will be moved to a separate repositories (e.g. `tf.contrib.probability --> tensorflow/probability`) and some are going to be deleted (e.g. `copy_graph`, `nearest_neighbor`).

For a full list of fates of the projects read [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md).